# Query with two selects and joins

Tags: mysql, join

In need of assistance forming a query that has two selects with joins. I am searching for duplicate entries within the same information, but the information is located in two tables.

Table ordermeta has orderid and formid.
Table orders has orderid and userid

I am joining ordermeta to orders twice and then searching for different orderids where formid and userid match.

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT om0.orderid AS order1, om1.orderid AS order2
FROM ordermeta om0
LEFT JOIN ordermeta om1 ON om0.formid = om0.formid
LEFT JOIN orders o0 ON om0.orderid = o0.orderid
LEFT JOIN orders o1 ON om1.orderid = o1.orderid
WHERE o0.userid = o1.userid
AND om0.orderid != om1.orderid
```

I also tried this but got thoroughly confused and moved to the above code:

```
SELECT order1.oid1, order1.pd1, order2.oid2, order2.pd2
FROM (
    SELECT o1.orderid AS oid1, paid AS pd1, uid AS uid1, fid AS fid1 
    FROM  `orders` o1
    JOIN ordermeta om1 ON o1.orderid = om1.orderid
) order1
JOIN (
    SELECT o2.orderid AS oid2, paid AS pd2, uid AS uid2, fid AS fid2 
    FROM  `orders` o2
    JOIN ordermeta om2 ON o2.orderid = om2.orderid
) order2 ON order1.uid1 = order2.uid2 AND order1.fid1 = order2.fid2
```

I get way too many results than what I'm expecting. Should be in the order of 1000, but am getting over 223000.

Sample Data:

```
ordermeta table
HEADER: omid, orderid, formid, <other data>
1, 101, 201, ...
2, 102, 202, ...
3, 103, 201, ...
4, 108, 201, ...
5, 109, 202, ...

orders table
HEADER: orderid, userid, <other data>
101, 2000, ...
102, 2000, ...
103, 2001, ...
108, 2000, ...
109, 2001, ...
```

First, I need to associate the userid to the ordermeta combining the formid. Then, search through the combined data for duplicates where formid=formid and userid=userid and return the two orderids.

In the sample above, I should get orderids 101 and 108 as their userids and formids are a match after being joined.

Comment: why not just join once?
`select * from orders o inner join ordermeta om on om.formid = o.userid and om.orderid <> o.orderid` that should give you all rows for which formid = userid, and for which orderids differ

Comment: some examples of the data that you consider duplicates would also be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will add data to the question above for clarity. I may be wrong, but I think I have to join the same tables twice to search for the duplicates. The first set of joins puts all the data into a single dataset, and then the second search to locate duplicates? I'm not looking for om.formid to equal o.userid; rather, when om1.formid = om2.formid AND o1.uid = o2.uid.

Comment: sorry, misread `where formid and userid match.` that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic was pretty close:

```
select * 
  from ordermeta om1
  inner join
  orders o1
    on om1.orderid = o1.orderid
  inner join
  ordermeta om2
    on om1.formid = om2.formid
  inner join 
  orders o2 
    on om2.orderid = o2.orderid
  where o1.userid = o2.userid
    and o1.orderid <> o2.orderid
```

Demo fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0936/1

In fact, your original query was fine if you didn't typo the join predicate for the two `ordermeta` tables

Comment: I found that after all this, I did have the query right at one point. I plugged yours and Bohemian's in and got the same number of responses. Found I needed to pull additional information from other tables to narrow my results down to the ~1000 I was looking for. Thanks for the quick responses and alternate ways to find the same data.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the first join condition:

```
LEFT JOIN ordermeta om1 ON om0.formid = om0.formid
```

Obviously a typo, but `om0.formid = om0.formid` is always true. Change it to:

```
LEFT JOIN ordermeta om1 ON om0.formid = om1.formid
```

You should move the conditions int he qhere clause into the join clauses too, so the whole query looks like:

```
SELECT om0.orderid AS order1, om1.orderid AS order2
FROM ordermeta om0
LEFT JOIN ordermeta om1 ON om0.formid = om0.formid
    AND om0.orderid != om1.orderid
LEFT JOIN orders o0 ON om0.orderid = o0.orderid
LEFT JOIN orders o1 ON om1.orderid = o1.orderid 
    AND o0.userid = o1.userid
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did catch the typo later on. Your answer and _pala's both get me the same information and verify I was close/correct at one point.